# pymongo generator fails - 'return' with argument inside generator

Tags: python, generator, pymongo

I am trying to do the following :

```
def get_collection_iterator(collection_name, find={}, criteria=None):
    collection = db[collection_name]
    # prepare the list of values of collection
    if collection is None:
        logging.error('Mongo could not return the collecton - ' + collection_name)
        return None

    collection = collection.find(find, criteria)
    for doc in collection:
        yield doc
```

and calling like :

```
def get_collection():
    criteria = {'unique_key': 0, '_id': 0}
    for document in Mongo.get_collection_iterator('contract', {}, criteria):
        print document
```

and I see the error saying :

```
File "/Users/Dev/Documents/work/dw/src/utilities/Mongo.py", line 96
    yield doc
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

what is that I am doing incorrect here?

Comment: @MattFenwick yes I did that noe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems the problem is that Python doesn't allow you to mix `return` and `yield` -- you use both within `get_collection_iterator`.

Clarification (thanks to rob mayoff): `return x` and `yield` can't be mixed, but a bare `return` can

Comment: You can use `return` with no argument in a generator.  You just can't use `return something`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the event `None` must be returned, but it is detected as a syntax error since the return would break the iteration loop.

Generators that are intended to use `yield` to handoff values in loops can't use return with argument values, as this would trigger a `StopIteration` error.  Rather than returning `None`, you may want to raise an exception and catch it in the calling context.

http://www.answermysearches.com/python-fixing-syntaxerror-return-with-argument-inside-generator/354/

```
def get_collection_iterator(collection_name, find={}, criteria=None):
    collection = db[collection_name]
    # prepare the list of values of collection
    if collection is None:
        err_msg = 'Mongo could not return the collecton - ' + collection_name
        logging.error(err_msg)
        raise Exception(err_msg)

    collection = collection.find(find, criteria)
    for doc in collection:
        yield doc
```

You could make a special exception for this too if need be.